# Is there any way to convince dialer not to use the primary mic?

Tags: cyanogenmod, microphone

I have Motorola Moto G 4G (Peregrine, XT1039), currently rooted and with CyanogenMod 12.1, and my primary microphone is mailfunctioning.

However, the camcorder mic works fine (audio is fine in video recordings).

Is there any way to convince the dialer to use that mic instead of the primary one? (Or an app that offers using the camcorder mic instead of the primary one - that would be ideal, but I didn't find any)

I've tried to manually reroute things for the stock dialer in `/system/etc/mixer_paths.xml`, and `/system/etc/audio_platform_info.xml`, but it didn't work.

Setting the device in `/system/etc/audio_platform_info.xml` seems to be completely ignored by the system, and with `/system/etc/mixer_paths.xml` I'm not completely sure what should be edited (I've tried setting ADC3, which is I think the camera mic, to higher volume in all profiles, and ADC1, which I guess is primary mic, to lower values - but that's not enough)

Comment: It turns out that sticking a needle  in the mic hole (violently) did the trick for me.